# Google Fusion Tables query (Google Map): add a Select All option in the drop-down filter

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

This question refers to a Google Map with a filter, created using the FusionTablesLayer Wizard.

Once a user has selected a filter value from the drop-down menu, the only way to revert back to the original map view (unfiltered, with all items showing on the map) is to refresh the whole page.

I'd like to add a "Select All" option to this query (or have it basically revert to select all if the user chooses the original "--Select--" option).  I've seen a few similar scenarios, but despite my best efforts (which are pretty awful), I can't replicate the solutions!

Here's the code in jsFiddle:   http://jsfiddle.net/j3GfP/

Answer (score 0):

You need to replicate the original query (with no "where" clause) when the --Select-- ("") or VIEW ALL ("*") entries are selected:

http://jsfiddle.net/4vBFV/4/

(updated with correct link above)

Comment: You are a king among kings.  I would have replied sooner, but I was still fiddling with things.....I was a bit perplexed because your example wasn't working for me -- until I finally realized I had to replace "--Select--" with "" and BINGO. Nice.  THank you so much for helping a total noob.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't "save" my working version.  Updated the link to the correct jsfiddle.